# Is worklight 5.0.6 same as worklight 6

Tags: version, ibm-mobilefirst, difference

i read some IBM links and it became unclear that either WL 5.0.6 is WL 6.0? Or is there any difference? If there is a difference then where i can get details of differences.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a new version - no it's not same as v5.0.6.
Worklight 6.0 contains new functionality, improved existing functionality, bug fixes, ... all that a new version should have.

Mobile Test Workbench, Geolocation, minification and concatenation for mobile web, operational analytics, and more. Go read [What's New in Worklight v6.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/start/c_what_s_new.html).

Comment: I see this is what was confusing to me. Thanks Idan. Can you please share me link for migrating WL from 5.0.6 to v6.0 ?

Comment: AAhad, start using the Information Center: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/r_migrating_to_a_newer_version_of_ibm_worklight.html